# SceneKit - Adding an image as Normal Map

Tags: swift, scenekit, collada

So far I was able to download a Collada file (dae) and show it on the screen.
Now I'm trying to programatically place an image in the Normal property, so the front texture will gain different effect.

According to the file inspector, the Normal option is under 
Materials -> Normal.

[image: Screenshow]

I have tried to change the 'Normal Map' contents through the material but without success.
This is my code that did not work.

```
/// Creating the Node
    let node = SCNNode()
    /// The dae file
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "bluebag.dae")
    let arryNode = scene?.rootNode.childNodes
    /// Override the assets
    for childNode in arryNode! {
        if let geo = childNode.geometry {
            for geoItem in geo.materials {
                geoItem.normal.contents = UIImage(named:"fabric.jpg") /// This is not working
            }
        }
        node.addChildNode(childNode)
    }
```

I have also tried to create a new node with material and Normal map image inside itself and add it to the front texture, but again I have no success.
Can please anybody point me how to add a normal map to a texture? am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
/// Creating the Node
let node = SCNNode()
/// The dae file
let scene = SCNScene(named: "bluebag.dae")
let arryNode = scene?.rootNode.childNodes                         // See Note 1
/// Override the assets
for childNode in arryNode! {
    if let geo = childNode.geometry {
        for geoItem in geo.materials {
            geoItem.normal.contents = UIImage(named:"fabric.jpg") // See Note 2
        }
    }
    node.addChildNode(childNode)
}
```

**Note 1**: Are you sure all your child nodes is on first level of rootNode?

**Note 2:** If you have fabric.jpg in Assets.xcassets then use `UIImage(named:"fabric")`

Try this to traverse node hierarchy:

```
scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
    if let geo = node.geometry {
        for material in geo.materials {
            material.normal.contents = UIImage(named: "fabric")
        }
    }
    scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node) // or something like this
}
```